# How to get updated state within a method? (React & Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm new to React and Redux so this could be the complete wrong way to go about things, but I'm trying to get the updated state within an `onSubmit` method.

This is a simple flashcard app and what I want to happen is to get a sentence from the user (`userInput`) and compare it against the correct sentence (`generated`). I'm able to get a list of correct and incorrect words based on their submission (done with the `compareInput()` action) which I can see in the Redux state, but this isn't updated until after method completely runs, so the way I currently have it set up, the initial length of the vectors `correct` and `wrong` are 0.

How can I get the updated state within the method? Or is there a better way to do this? I can do it in `componentDidUpdate`, but since the state is updating with each change in the form, I thought it would be unnecessary overhead calculate the correct percentage (`pctCorrect`) each update.

Thanks a ton!

`Input.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {
    compareInput, generateSentence, trackProgress
} from '../../actions/learn';

export class Input extends Component {

    state = {
        userInput: '',
        progress: { submissions: 0, pctCorrect: 1 },
    }

    onSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { sentence } = this.props.sentence;
        const { userInput } = this.state;
        this.props.compareInput({
            'generated': sentence,
            'user_input': userInput,
        });
        this.props.generateSentence();
        this.setState({ userInput: '' })

        this.props.trackProgress({
            progress: {
                submissions: this.props.progress.submissions + 1,
                pctCorrect: this.props.correct.length / (
                    this.props.correct.length + this.props.wrong.length
                )
            },
        })

        render() { };

        const mapStateToProps = state => ({
            sentence: state.learnReducer.sentence,
            progress: state.learnReducer.progress,
            correct: state.learnReducer.correct,
            wrong: state.learnReducer.wrong,
        })

        export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
            compareInput, generateSentence, trackProgress
        })(Input);
```

Comment: could you include what these redux actions/reducers look like?

Comment: Why are you trying to access the updated state from within onSubmit?

Comment: @LucasRaza To calculate `pctCorrect`, which needs the updated values after the submit. Maybe it's better to do the calculation somewhere else, but even in the actions the state is still not updated until after `onSubmit` completely runs

Comment: @LucasRaza but also as I mentioned I am pretty new to this so if there is an obviously better way to do this I am just not aware of it :)

Answer (score 1):

React components can't access newer values from props until they re-render.  Doesn't matter whether it's a class or function component, or if the component is dispatching a Redux action or a callback from a parent.  React hasn't yet been able to re-render by the time the next line runs, and `props` will still be pointing to the existing props anyway.

If you absolutely need to access the latest values from the Redux store immediately after dispatching an action, move the logic into a thunk so that you have access to `getState`:

```js
// An example of checking state after a dispatch
function checkStateAfterDispatch() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        const firstState = getState();
        dispatch({type : "FIRST_ACTION"});

        const secondState = getState();

        if(secondState.someField != firstState.someField) {
            dispatch({type : "SECOND_ACTION"});
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay that's what I figured... How would you recommend doing what I am trying to do? Would the calculation be better in `componentDidUpdate` or is your method above a better way to go? Thanks for your help btw

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to say because I _don't_ know what you're trying to do overall - I don't know what `compareInput`, `generateSentence`, or `trackProgress` do. That said, I'd suggest applying some of the Redux Style Guide suggestions like [model actions as "events", not "setters"](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#model-actions-as-events-not-setters), and [put as much logic as possible in reducers](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#put-as-much-logic-as-possible-in-reducers). It's possible you could do this with a single action dispatch instead of multiples.

Comment: You can also try [deriving values from the state](https://redux.js.org/recipes/computing-derived-data) instead of explicitly storing them.  For example, the "percent done" could be calculated while rendering, instead of having to put it in the store.

Comment: Ah so `compareInput` just compares the correct string against the inputted string from the user, `generateSentence` just fetches a flashcard from the backend (just a sentence rn), and `trackProgress` just monitors the performance of the user, which includes the `pctCorrect` which is the percentage of flashcards that the user got correct (on a per word basis).

Comment: So in each "session' the user would go through 10 notecards or something and then after each submission, the percentage correct would be calculated and shown, the only problem is when I calculate it with `onSubmit` it is calculating the percentage correct from the previous submission.

Comment: I'm not sure if the "deriving values from state" would help because I think they need to be stored because I need to keep the running tally of correct and incorrect words across submissions for a given round -- does that make sense? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: If you need to know `a + b = c`, and you have `a` and `b` stored, you can always run the `a + b = c` calculation whenever need.  That's "deriving data".  So, rather than calculating the percentage complete and putting _that_ in the store, you can calculate the percentage as needed and just keep updating the values that go into that.

Comment: Okay thanks that makes sense. One more question, where should I put the calculation to get it "as needed" I can't do it when the form is submitted, and `componentDidMount` would calculate too often. I could easily get this done if I just knew where to put it haha

Comment: Nevermind, I just tried doing it in `componentDidUpdate` and I got the error `Maximum update depth exceeded`. Now I really have no idea where it could go :/

Comment: I don't know where the calculation is needed, so I can't say for sure. You may be misunderstanding what I'm suggestion. I'm not saying to _dispatch an action with the results of the calculation.  I'm saying to do `const c = a + b` any time you need `c`, whether it be in the middle of rendering, or elsewhere.